# Почему программы и система виснут при использовании OpenCL?

Tags: photoshop, windows-8, opencl

У меня по какой-то причине при включении программы, которая использует OpenCL происходит полное провисание всей Windows 8.1 намертво. То есть экран просто застывает, не реагирует ни на мышь, ни на клавиатуру. Приходится просто перезагружать ноутбук.
Я проверил оперативку, жесткий диск, процессор - все тесты пройдены, все работает нормально. Драйвера для Intel HD4600 и GeForce GT 755M обновлены. Система прошла проверку на целостность системных файлов. В программе GPU Caps Viewer спокойно запускаются все проверки работы OpenGL, OpenCL, Cuda, Vulkan.
Приходится использовать Фотошоп 32-битной версии, 64 уводит систему в полный отказ.
Интересно, что это произошло буквально месяц назад, когда я почти не трогал Photoshop CC 64bit и он спокойно работал. Поэтому, если вдруг понадобится функционал Photoshop CC 64bit, то придется решать эту проблему, что я сейчас и делаю.
Вижу, что проблема довольно сложная, потому что в интернете ответов не нахожу, такое ощущение, что моя проблема уникальна, ну буду рад если кто-то, хоть что-то подскажет

Answer (score 1):

Поставил драйвер для встроенный видеокарты постарее - OpenCL заработал. Правда теперь не работают возможности 3D в Фотошопе